# Date input with vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to create two inputs which allow you to choose the date of the creation from a given spell of time (basically, the first input is "from" and the second one is "to").

[image]

But I can't figure out a way how to do it! Has anyone done something like this? I would really appreciate your help (so far I've just come up with the basic

```
<vs-input color="dark" type="date" v-model="date" label="Дата создания" class="form-control" />
```

but it doesn't look very good and I have no idea how to add "from" and "to" buttons to it :(

Also, is there a way to add a label to a slider? I tried to add something like this

```
<vs-slider :min="0" max="500000" color="danger" label="Slider" v-model="slider"/>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using a component library?

Comment: @EnriqueBermúdez a few of them, actually, which one do you mean?

Comment: `<vs-input>` and `<vs-slider>`, for example

Comment: @EnriqueBermúdez yes, I do use them

Comment: My question is: which component library is that? Or are they custom components made by you?

Comment: please if you use a library for custom component mention it in your tags